# Изменить текст button при удачной отправке письма

Tags: javascript, button, phpmailer

```
<form action="mail-call.php" method="post">
    <p>Заказать звонок</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="tel_number" required>
    <button name="reserve_submit">Заказать звонок</button>
</form>
```

Это код формы с кнопкой. После нажатия и удачной валидации полей отправляется письмо с использованием `phpmailer`.

Хочу изменить текст на кнопке при удачной отправке письма. Ибо при `onlick` текст изменится даже в случае, если поля заполнены неправильно.

К какому событию (или к чему-то другому) можно привязаться, чтоб грамотно это реализовать?

Думал, что можно сделать через `button.onsubmit = function() {this.innerHTML = 'Отправлено'}`, но, видимо, это событие для других целей...

Comment: Предоставьте код отправки данных (те, которые на `JS`) и то, что может ответить сервер при удаче и ошибке.

Comment: @Other если я вас правильно понял, то JS я не использую в этих целях. ибо вся отправка идет через php: начиная с `<?php
  if(isset( $_POST['reserve_submit'] )) {`  ... формируется тело письма ...  и заканчивая '$mail->Send();'

Comment: Если так, то текст поменять динамически не выйдет. Либо перезагрузка страницы и вместо формы красивая табличка "Отправлено!", но это давно не в тренде, сейчас формы без `AJAX` - это что-то из эры австралопитеков (не всегда, но в общем...).

Comment: @Other а можете привести пример ajax-запроса, в котором будет, к чему привязаться для решения моей задачи?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/524251/207618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:

**PHP:**
в конце файла ввёл переменную, чтобы получать её в качестве подтверждения от сервера, что всё прошло удачно

```
<?php
  if( $_POST ) {
  ...
  ...  // формирование тела письма и вызов класса 'class.phpmailer.php' );
  ...
    if ( $mail->send() ) {
      $result = '1';
    } else {
      $result = '0';
    }
    die( $result );  // завершение работы скрипта и вывод результата в переменную
  }
?>
```

**JS:**
Используя jQuery, сформировал AJAX запрос

```
var data = $('#modalCallOrder form').serialize();  // собираю и упорядочиваю данные в форме
$.ajax({
  url: "mail.php",       // путь к файлу с кодом для формирования тела письма
  type: "POST",          // указываю метод отправки
  data: data,            // указываю данные для передачи на сервер
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('#modal button').text('Отправляется...');  // перед отправкой письма меняю текст кнопки
  },
  success: function(result) {      // получаю ответ от сервера
    if ( result == 1 ) {           // если 1, значит письмо отправлено
      console.log('Письмо отправлено');
      $('#modal button').text('Отправлено');   // после отправки письма меняю текст кнопки
      $('#modal form').find('input').val('');  // очищаю введённые значения
    } else {
      console.log('Ошибка отправки');
    }
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log('Ошибка доступа')
  }
})
```

**HTML:**
Код формы очистил от данных про путь к php-файлу и метод отправки

```
<form>
    <p>Заказать звонок</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="tel_number" required>
    <button>Заказать звонок</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> К какому событию (или к чему-то другому) можно привязаться, чтоб грамотно это реализовать?

Насколько я понял, Вам, по какой-то причине нужно сделать это действие "инлайново", в этом случае, слушайте событие `submit` на форме. Но **по-хорошему**, Вам нужно удостовериться, что письмо действительно было отправлено и сервер положительно ответил.

```
 <form action="mail-call.php" method="post" onsubmit="_onSubmit(event)">
        <p>Заказать звонок</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="tel_number" required>
        <input type="submit" name="reserve_submit" value="Заказать звонок">
    </form>

    <script>
        function _onSubmit(e) {
            document.forms[0].elements[2].value = 'Отправлено!';
            e.preventDefault(); // debug purposes
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[По просьбе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524219/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-button-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0?noredirect=1#comment648825_524219) привожу пример `AJAX`-отправки:

```
// mail-call.php
// Получаем данные, обрабатываем, отправляем и пр.
$name = trim($_POST['name']);
$phone = trim($_POST['tel_number']);
$response = [
    'status' => false
];

if($name === '' || $phone === '')
    $response['error'] = 'Имя и телефон должны быть заполненными';
else if(!preg_match('/^\d\-\d{3}\-\d{3}$/', $phone))
    $response['error'] = 'Телефон должен быть вида: 1-234-567';
else{
    $response['status'] = true;
    $response['name'] = $name;
    $response['phone'] = $phone;
}

print json_encode($response);

// Страница заказа
<form action="/mail-call.php" method="post" id='orderForm'>
    <p>Заказать звонок</p>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваше имя" name="name" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Ваш телефон" name="tel_number" required>
    <button name="reserve_submit">Заказать звонок</button>
</form>
<script>
    function submitHandler(e){
        // Ищем кнопку отправки (в ней будем писать ответ) и предотвращаем стандартное действие браузера
        let submit = this.querySelector('[name="reserve_submit"]');
        e.preventDefault();

        // Это новый метод запросов, в старых браузерах не работает
        // Но удобный, отправляет всё в PHP-обработчик
        fetch(this.action, {
            method: this.method,
            body: new FormData(this)
        }).then(raw => raw.json().then(success => {
            // Как только получили ответ, смотрим статус
            if(success.status){
                // Отлично, пишем что всё отправилось
                submit.innerHTML = success.name + ", принято на: " + success.phone;
            }else{
                // Если статус провалил явки, можно написать причину
                // В моём примере в ответ добавляется причина (error)
                submit.innerHTML = "Произошла ошибка: " + success.error;
            }
        })).catch(error => 
            // Если произошла ошибка в JS, обрабатываем тут
            submit.innerHTML = "Ошибка отправки"
        );
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        // Навешиваем обработчик отправки на форму
        document.querySelector('#orderForm').addEventListener('submit', submitHandler);
    });
</script>
```

Пример рабочий, `PHP5.6`, `Chrome50`, `FF42`.